# yapf is formatting my VSCode Python function summaries weirdly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, yapf

For some reason, with format on save enabled, yapf formats my VSCode python function/summary from this

```
print('hi')

"""_summary_
Pretty-prints a json object
"""
def print_json(json_obj):
    print(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4))
```

to this

```
print('hi')
"""_summary_
Pretty-prints a json object
"""


def print_json(json_obj):
    print(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this weird behavior? The pretty standard function summary was generated by right-clicking on `print_json` and clicking "Generate Docstring".